# Bash script error “awk fatal cannot open file for reading (no such file or directory)”

Tags: bash, find

The issue I'm having is one where the directories are not found.
The errors I encounter are:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/a/dir/notdone/test.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/a/dir/notdone/test.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `/a/dir/notdone/test.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

and:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘/a/dir/notdone/test.txt’: No such file or directory
```

I'm sure I'm missing something to do the current directory bash is using and the names that are passed to awk, but I can't figure it out, for all the changes I've made to the script.

Comment: The error messages you get are very clear, there is no such file or directory. Possibly if you remove the initial slash, then the file path exists?

Comment: I tried that initially, but the script starts searching at the root directory and going through all the folders for everything.

Comment: `find` returns filenames for `while read -r filename` with paths and you prefix `${filename}` again with another path in `$(awk ... ${notdone}/${filename})`

Comment: Had a little mishap with the removal of the initial slash, whereby the contents of my webserver root were all moved into the /done folder ^_^. Lesson learned. i had been trying to use the `-printf "%f\n"` command, but I hadn't understood it fully. I'll go through the `man find` docs and start learning to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed and improved your script.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

basedir="$HOME/t"
notdonedir="$basedir/notdone"
donedir="$basedir/done"

# Declare binary flags
declare -a flags=(HAS_COUNTRY HAS_DISTRICT HAS_TOWN)
for bit in "${!flags[@]}"; do
  declare -ri "${flags[bit]}"=$((1 << bit))
done
declare -ri HAS_ALL=$((2 ** ${#flags[@]} - 1))

declare -i fields_flags

# Find all files whose name match the *.txt pattern
# within the notdone directory, and output a null
# delimited stream of file names
find "$notdonedir/" -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 |
  
  # Iterate read the file names from the null delimited stream
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do

    # Clear these values
    unset country district town
    fields_flags=0

    # While either one of country, district or town is empty AND
    # There are key value pairs to read from the file
    while {
      # No need to keep reading key values from the file
      # if all of country district and town are captured
      ((fields_flags != HAS_ALL))
    } && {
      # Read key value pair OR just check a key has been read
      # if End-Of-File has been reached before last New-Line character
      IFS=': ' read -r -d $'\n' key value || [ "$key" ]
    }; do

      # Conditionally assign value to variable depending on key name
      # and flag field acquisition
      case "$key" in
        'country')
          country=$value
          ((fields_flags |= HAS_COUNTRY))
          ;;
        'district')
          district=$value
          ((fields_flags |= HAS_DISTRICT))
          ;;
        'town')
          town=$value
          ((fields_flags |= HAS_TOWN))
          ;;
        *) continue ;;
      esac
    done <"$filename" # Stream this file to the while read loop

    # If all of country, district, town has a value
    if ((fields_flags == HAS_ALL)); then

      # Print format into the sql vairable an SQL query
      printf -v sql \
        'INSERT INTO some_table (country,district,town) VALUES("%s","%s","%s")' \
        "$country" "$district" "$town"

      # If the SQL query is successful
      if mysql --user=some_user --password=some_pass some_table <<<"$sql"; then

        # Move file to done directory
        mv -- "$filename" "$donedir/"
      else
        printf 'Error while processing file: %s\n' \
          "${notdonedir}/${filename}" >&2
        break
      fi

    else
      printf 'One of country, district or town entries is empty!\n' >&2
    fi
  done
```

Comment: Thanks for the revised and improved code. I've tested it and am having one issue with it. When the txt files only contains 3 lines, the error relating to the mising entries is thrown up for the last value, in this case being the 'town'. If I add a fourth line to the txt file, everything works correctly. Is this due to the if/then statement?

Comment: @MeltingCube when the last line does not end with a newline, the `read` returns false and the `while` loop exit prematurely without handling the values. I fixed the script to handle this case with: `while IFS=': ' read -r -d $'\n' key value || [ "$key" ]`, so if `read`fail because of end of file before end of line, it checks if something has been read into the `$key` variable, and if so, continue to enter the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for that, it works perfectly. Aside from the solution, it's great for me to be able to see another way to solve the same issue so that I can expand my way of doing things.

Comment: @MeltingCube Updated the script to binary flags for fields acquisition

Comment: OK, so I had just gotten done slightly modifying the `if` statement in your previous version to take into account the case that not all three values are present, but rather the combination of country+district or country+town, using `if [[ -n "$country" && -n "$district" ]] || [[ -n "$country" && -n "$town" ]]; then` . How do I apply that to the above version of the code? I've tried changing the `while` and `if` statements, but can't achieve what I would like. Is it something to do with the declarations? The flags are defined so I thought i could reference them alone in the `if` statement.

Comment: @MeltingCube then you do `if (( fields_flags & HAS_COUNTRY && ( fields_flags & HAS_DISTRICT || fields_flags & HAS_TOWN ) )); then` but you loose the advantage of packing flags into a single variable to compare with a single value `fields_flags`

Comment: With the above, I get the missing field warning.

I'm learning with the previous script version, trying to UPDATE rows of the database, based on the country being the primary/unique column, but it doesn't work. I get an error saying "command not found". It works on command line.
Current INSERT section:

`printf -v sql \
        'INSERT INTO some_table (country,district,town) VALUES("%s","%s","%s")' \
        "$country" "$district" "$town"`
and mine:
`printf -v sql \
 'UPDATE table SET district='\"$district\"', town='\"$town\"'  WHERE country='\"$country\"''`

Comment: Apologies for the above format. The limited space made it a crunch. I can ask as a separate question if necessary, as the point can stand alone from the searching I did yesterday for examples.

Comment: @MeltingCube please make this a different question post with minimal reproducible example and code snippet as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The script uses 'find' to generate list of file names. Each file name will contain the full path (/a/dir/notdone/filename.txt), so there is no need to prefix the file name again in the awk/mv commands:

```
    country=$(awk -F":" '/^country/ { print $2 }' "${filename}")
    district=$(awk -F":" '/^district/ { print $2 }' "${filename}")
    town=$(awk -F":" '/^town/ { print $2 }' "${filename}")

    ...
    mv "${filename}" ${done}/
```

Admittingly, this does not explain the error message. But it might solve the problem.

Comment: This actually worked perfectly and I'm sad I didn't notice this originally.